# Camera option was not shown in fileChooserIntent in Android version 10 and when using Android SDK 29

Tags: android

When we try to upload profile picture/take new picture the fileChooserIntent showing gallery option only and camera option was not shown in the list.

Answer (score 0):

add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" inside application tag in manifest.xml file.

`<application 
     android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"> 
  </application>`

Answer (score 0):

If you target Android 10 or higher, set the value of requestLegacyExternalStorage to true in your app's manifest file.

Go through this for more details. https://medium.com/@pednekarshashank33/android-10s-scoped-storage-image-picker-gallery-camera-d3dcca427bbf